# Get a BitMap Image from IP Camera, UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, raspberry-pi3, iot, windows-10-iot-core

I want to get Image from IP Camera with using RaspberryPI3, that I wrote this code but when I click Button, system is going down, an exception thrown in App.g.i.cs, How can I fix that code?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.Web.Http;


namespace App6
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Sample()
    {
        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("http://192.168.1.253/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Motion")).OpenReadAsync();

        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

        byte[] bytes = pixelData.DetachPixelData();


        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            await stream.WriteAsync(bytes.AsBuffer());
            stream.Seek(0);
            await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }
            IpCamera_1.Source = image; //IpCamera_1 is Image.

    }

    private void Hello_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Sample();
    }
}
}
```

Is there another solution that streaming video from IP Camera to Raspberry-Pi? I am using Windows-10-iot-core.

Comment: You should track down where exactly the exception happens (after which line the app crashes). Put a breakpoint in the `Sample` method and go line-by-line to see what is happening.

Comment: Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("http://192.168.1.253/SnapShotJPEG?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Motion")).OpenReadAsync();                    after this statement

Comment: What type of exception are you getting?  Is there an inner exception?

Comment: if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();       This code block inside the App.g.i.cs file

Answer (score 1):

Because you are connecting to local network, you should add some required capabilities to your `Package.appxmanifest`. Right-click the file in solution explorer, select `View code` and in the `<Capabilities>` element add the following:

```
<Capabilities>
  <Capability Name="internetClient" />
  <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
  <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: Again I get same exception that                                                                      `if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

Comment: The `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` parameter has a `Exception` property which could contain more information about what went wrong. Also the `InnerException` might give even more info

Comment: `#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif`         this is the related inner exception, I don't understand what is happening in there. :(

Comment: But if you hover over the `e` parameter, doesn't it show anything useful?

Comment: Yes, there is an unhandled exception like `{Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}`

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add the `webcam` capability to your `Package.appxmanifest`.

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
```

Capabilities must be declared in your Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app's package manifest to access certain API or resources like pictures, music, or devices like the camera or the microphone. You can refer to [App capability declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations).

> The webcam capability provides access to the video feed of a built-in camera or external webcam, which allows the app to capture photos and videos. On Windows, apps must handle the case in which the user has disabled the camera from the Settings charm.
>   The webcam capability only grants access to the video stream. In order to grant access to the audio stream as well, the microphone capability must be added.